# Capturing a json response

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to retrieve exchange pricing info in json format for a data aggregation project. One api is giving me problems.

Calling a url in my browser shows exactly what I need, but my calls are raising errors.
I'm wondering if I'm dealing with a malformed response, not understanding some encoding/decoding issues, or if I am just not seeing something obvious.

I've tried as many different solutions as I can google in 48 hours after what seemed obvious didn't work. I'll put a couple of examples below.
Basically tho, just need to get the response I see by calling the url directly into something I can read.

```
import requests
import json


r = requests.get('https://www.nlexch.com/api/v2/tickers/ltcbtc.json')
print(r)
<Response [200]>
```

..

```
r = requests.get('https://www.nlexch.com/api/v2/tickers/ltcbtc.json')

response_data = r.json()
print(response)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Mega2\Projects\Unobot\nlex-test.py", line 5, in <module>
    response_data = r.json()
  File "C:\Users\encry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\encry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\encry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\encry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What I am expecting to get is what my browser shows at
https://www.nlexch.com/api/v2/tickers/ltcbtc.json

which at this moment is:

```
{"at":1567086780,"ticker":{"buy":"0.005","sell":"0.02","low":"0.00685","high":"0.00685","last":"0.00685","vol":"15.80093851"}}
```

I looked hard before posting this, to see if there were similar issues resolved. Indeed, I found several approaches that seemed like they should just work out of the box. Nothing I tried yielded the simple result I need.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I just want to be sure that you are getting http 200 in the same request where you are getting the error. So do the get, then print(response), and then print(response.json).

Comment: Just checked on my side and it looks like the api is returning malformed json. I get 200 but also get the decoding error.

Comment: You might need to send something in the request header to get the json. I think that your request response is just html.

Comment: BTW - Welcome to Stack Overflow. For your first question, this was very nicely done - Kudos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find, if you were to print (r.text) in your example, you will get the google search page. It appears the destination is looking for a valid user agent. When I insert an agent, it seems to work. Note that the text is valid json, and I can now pull the json response.

```
import requests
import json


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.nlexch.com/api/v2/tickers/ltcbtc.json'
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
    j = r.json()
    print(j['ticker'])
```

Comment: Yes, that absolutely solved my problem. Thanks so much. It was driving me mad.